# jupyterlab/plotly-extension won't install

Tags: plotly, jupyter-lab

Jupyterlab 0.31.8
Ubuntu 14.04
Plotly 3.0.0

I'm trying to install the Plotly jupyterlab extension.

Running `jupyter labextension install @jupyterlab/plotly-extension --debug` results in

```
> /usr/bin/npm pack @jupyterlab/plotly-extension
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:jupyterlab/plotly-extension Cloning into bare repository '/home/ubuntu/.npm/_git-remotes/git-github-com-jupyterlab-plotly-extension-8ab9f472'...
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:jupyterlab/plotly-extension Permission denied (publickey).
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:jupyterlab/plotly-extension fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:jupyterlab/plotly-extension
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:jupyterlab/plotly-extension Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:jupyterlab/plotly-extension and the repository exists.
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install jupyterlab/plotly-extension
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, stat 'jupyterlab/plotly-extension'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-144-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "pack" "@jupyterlab/plotly-extension"
npm ERR! cwd /tmp/tmp0ce5jqp6
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.37
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! path jupyterlab/plotly-extension
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /tmp/tmp0ce5jqp6/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jupyterlab/labextensions.py", line 71, in start
ans = self.run_task()

  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jupyterlab/labextensions.py", line 100, in run_task
for arg in self.extra_args

  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jupyterlab/labextensions.py", line 100, in <listcomp>
for arg in self.extra_args

  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jupyterlab/commands.py", line 210, in install_extension
return handler.install_extension(extension)

  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jupyterlab/commands.py", line 347, in install_extension
info = self._install_extension(extension, tempdir)

  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jupyterlab/commands.py", line 1095, in _install_extension
info = self._extract_package(extension, tempdir)

  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jupyterlab/commands.py", line 1135, in _extract_package
raise ValueError(msg % source)

ValueError: "@jupyterlab/plotly-extension" is not a valid npm package


Errored, use --debug for full output:
ValueError: "@jupyterlab/plotly-extension" is not a valid npm package
```

What I tried was the standard recommendation found here https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyter-renderers/tree/master/packages/plotly-extension

What should I do differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working after trying quite a few things. My guess is that one (or both) of these two things is what made it work:

1) Upgrade to Jupyterlab 0.34.12

2) Install nodejs using these two lines:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash - && \
apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Answer (score 2):

Although the answer is accepted, if any problem still persists and behind a proxy connection, try setting the proxy in npm config. 

Example ->

```
npm config set http-proxy=""
npm config set https-proxy=""
```

Comment: This turned out to be my problem.